# name 'float' is not defined : Starklark / Bazel

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to add floating-point operations to my `.bzl` file. According to the Bazel globals specification, the `float()` function should be defined, as per the Starlark specification. However, when I try to add `float()`, I get the following error,

`ERROR: /home/username/code/project/foo.bzl:4:3: name 'float' is not defined`

Is there anything else I have to import? I assume that since the `float()` keyword is defined in the global namespace I wouldn't need to import it. According to the [starlark spec page](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/language.html) on the Bazel site page, `float`s are not supported, but this directly conflicts with the [float() specification on the global page](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/globals.html#float).

update: running Bazel 3.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [build Bazel from master](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-compile-source.html) it does already support `float`. I added Bazel from master to my system via the alias `potato`. Bazel 3.7.2 (and earlier) does not support the `float` type. I guess we won't see any float support in 3.7.x.

If you need floating point math for Bazel 3.7.2 and earlier you have to implement floating-point math using integer tricks. See for instance [here](http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/fp/sunfp.html).

Maybe you can achieve your goal without requiring float as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374262/how-to-emulate-float-double-real-in-bazel) or by falling back to a "normal" Python script.

BTW: In the documentation, you can switch to the current used Bazel version - which will give you 404 for float and Bazel 3.7.2 and earlier. Only for master, there is documentation available.

Comment: Thanks! I was using fixed point integer tricks as a fallback.

Answer (score 2):

A version of Bazel supporting floating point numbers has not been released yet. Presumably, the version after 4.0 will support them.